# Where does drupal_mail() get the return-path and sender?

Tags: emails

I want to send a simple mail using `drupal_mail()`. I don't understand from where it gets sender and incorrect_mail@gmail.com as return path. From where does it get this email?

```
function rappel_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch($key) {
    case 'informations':
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body']= $params['body'];
      break;       
  }
}

function my_module_passwordOublie_envoie_password ($email) {
  $response = array();
  global $language;
  $mail_user = user_load_by_mail($email);
  if (!$mail_user) {
    return func_succes(950, $response); // just to check if mail exists
  }
  else {
    $to = 'my.real.email@gmail.com'; 
    $from = 'noreplay@noreplay.com';

    $params = array(
      'body' => t("hi, you've just received a drupal mail"),
      'subject' => t("test mailing"),
    );
    $message = drupal_mail('rappel', 'informations', $to, $language->language, $params, $from, TRUE);
   }
 }
```

This is Postman response (because I'm working with services on a custom resource that send mail using `drupal_mail()`).

```
"Return-Path": "????@gmail.com", <=== those emails are valid (mine too but i've delete this email every where it was ! )
"Sender": "????@gmail.com",<=========
"From": "noreplay@noreplay.com" <=== good one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`drupal_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7.x) gets the value for those headers either from the the value of the *site_mail* persistent variable (set in admin/config/system/site-information), or from the *sendmail_from* setting found in php.ini.

The first line of `drupal_email()` show exactly how the default value for the sender is set.

```
$default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));
```

This is then the code that sets the email headers.

```
  if ($default_from) {

    // To prevent e-mail from looking like spam, the addresses in the Sender and
    // Return-Path headers should have a domain authorized to use the originating
    // SMTP server.
    $headers['From'] = $headers['Sender'] = $headers['Return-Path'] = $default_from;
  }
  if ($from) {
    $headers['From'] = $from;
  }
  $message['headers'] = $headers;
```

Comment: Thank you i totally forget the site mail information.. is there any "configuration" to set in order to receive mail ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- do you want the Drupal site to receive mail somehow?

Comment: no, when i send mail, postman says that mail is sent but if i check my mail there's no drupal mail, note that i'm not working in localhost, can you tell me if there is a drupal or smtp configuration to add please ?

Comment: Drupal core's mail system will use the sendmail program configured in your PHP.ini -- there's nothing to configure on the Drupal end. Maybe your server's sendmail isn't configured correctly. If you would prefer to use a SMTP server, try the SMTP module at https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp.